# i am using WebKitBrowser in vb.net. it is not firing keydown event but preview keydown is working properly. can anyone tell me whats happening?

Tags: vb.net, webkit

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebKitBrowser1.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebKitBrowser1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles WebKitBrowser1.KeyDown
        MessageBox.Show("keydown")
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebKitBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles WebKitBrowser1.PreviewKeyDown
        MessageBox.Show("preview key down")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer in global issue maybe occur when you expect the keydown event raising.

> Some key presses, such as the TAB, RETURN, ESC, and arrow keys, are
>   typically ignored by some controls because they are not considered
>   input key presses. For example, by default, a Button control ignores
>   the arrow keys. Pressing the arrow keys typically causes the focus to
>   move to the previous or next control. The arrow keys are considered
>   navigation keys and pressing these keys typically do not raise the
>   KeyDown event for a Button. However, pressing the arrow keys for a
>   Button does raise the PreviewKeyDown event. By handling the
>   PreviewKeyDown event for a Button and setting the IsInputKey property
>   to true, you can raise the KeyDown event when the arrow keys are
>   pressed. However, if you handle the arrow keys, the focus will no
>   longer move to the previous or next control.

Read the complete discussion on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx

Additionally in jQuery and other libraries and extensions you should read documentation and then decide to choose event, methods, etc. In my opinion if  event1 (for example PreviewKeyDown event)
 working for me (surely I must check difference scenarios maybe happen) without unwanted issues or decreasing efficiency comparing to the event2 (for example KeyDown event) I'll using it.

Hope this help.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it is not working with input keys as well.

Comment: @AnkushAgrawal please explain more. Is PreviewKeyDown event not work for you? in witch situation? in what input keys?

Comment: PreviewKeyDown event is working properly with all the keys, but KeyDown event is not working with any key.

Comment: @AnkushAgrawal So why not using PreviewKeyDown? If your question just about curious to know whats happening in key stroke cause KeyDown isn't works and PreviewKeyDown is working, I Answered and you can read link to understand the reason. Please accept as answer if this is.